# Swapping Primary URLs between two sites

Tags: url

We have two sites and need to swap the primary URLs.

URLone.com is a landing page that links to URLtwo.com, which is a full website.

We now want the Full website to have URLone.com as it's primary URL, then redirect URLtwo.com to the primary.

I told IT guys to just change DNS settings. Is that wrong? We shouldn't need to move any files, right?

Comment: This depends on what kind of server you're running and how it's set up.

Answer (score 1):

Just changing the DNS is unlikely to work - and will indeed likely break things except in the very rare case where (a) you rare not using HTTPS and (b) your website is the default for the server - which is extremely unlikely unless you have dedicated hosting.

If you are not using HTTPS, you should be.  If you are using DNS, HTTPS will likely not accept the site as valid because the certificate won't have the appropriate domain name associated with it.

If the 2 websites are on different servers, you will either need to reconfigure the servers and the DNS or move the files between the servers.

Comment: Don't forget that they should implement redirects from pages on the old full site other than the home page to the new location if they want to preserve SEO.